# Question oblivion dimension

Tags: discussion, questions

It is in my understanding that StackOverflow is a self-driven community Q&A. As such, questions, answer and comments are valuable. A Google search is enough to meet the big StackExchange community. A non-community member would search information based upon value and other people might do it too.

When I post something and there is no vote nor any comment, it basically mean nobody will get it. The idea I was trying to communicate is a failure. Natural flow will put the non-valuable question in the deepest oblivion of unanswered/ignored question so it will become less likely to appear as a Google search result.

Should I delete my own unrated questions/answers then?

Comment: I think you should wait for the questions to be noticed by someone - which may happen soon enough (if the question isn't too obscure.) If that doesn't work, you set a bounty on the question (if you've earned enough reputation to do so).

Comment: Be aware that there are secret and mystical algorithms written by ancient Mayan prophets that run on SE sites. These algorithms track things like deleted posts, negative votes, etc and if you do it too much they may ban you from asking any more questions (it's to stop spamming and trolling). The algorithm will punish you for deleting questions with negative scores, and new users (who don't know this) often have trouble with that little 'Gotcha'. (Doing it once or twice won't hurt). SE likes to have questions, even if they're not answered, so you should only remove it if it's a bad question.

Comment: Google (nor any of the other search engines) uses votes here as part of their search algorithms. If you're using the right terms your question should be easily discoverable.

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately it's up to you*. But votes aren't a perfect measure of the value of a question or answer to future visitors.

- Do you think your answer was correct, and might be helpful to future visitors? I'd leave it.
- Is your question still a real problem you face? I'd leave it, for a while at least - after a month or two, reevaluate and maybe delete.

All this assumes a net score of 0. If one of my answers falls below 0, I'll reevaluate its quality, and be more inclined to delete.

<sub>* to a certain extent. Questions with answers cannot be deleted.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> Should I delete my own unrated questions/answers then?

On Stack Overflow, and some other Stack Exchange sites, deleting your questions would cause you not to be able to ask further questions.

If your question doesn't have any answer, you can add more details, or make your question more specific. After that, you just need to wait. If somebody knows the answer, s/he will answer you, even if it could pass a month before it happens.

What you can also make is to show the link to your question to those users who can possibly answer it.